# NaN when calling function after declaring function twice and using numbers as default values in one of those functions

Tags: javascript

Edited question.
I get NaN when I call the function and the function is declared twice. So that should be the issue. But why is that happening?
in the example below:

`console.log(typeof monitorCount());`// it prints out number

I was expecting 15 when I called the monitorCount() function. But I get NaN even though when I do typeof(monitorCount()) it gives me a number.

```js
function monitorCount(rows=5,columns=3){
    console.log(typeof rows,typeof columns);
    return rows*columns;
}
console.log(monitorCount());
console.log(typeof monitorCount());
function monitorCount(rows,columns){
    console.log(typeof rows,typeof columns);

    return rows*columns;
}
```

When using this example declaring the function only once it works as expected printing out 15. So why it doesn't work in the previous example and it works here?

```js
function monitorCount(rows=5,columns=3){
    console.log(typeof rows,typeof columns);
    return rows*columns;
}
console.log(monitorCount());
```

Comment: I tried it in the latest Chrome (through DevTools) and there it works just fine: `monitorCount()` produces 15. Please **[edit]** the question and explain where or how you run this code, including which javascript engine or environment you are using.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: NaN is of type number.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that at least allows us to reproduce the problem. "* the function is declared twice. So that should be the issue.*" - yes it is. Don't do that, why would you? "* But why is that happening?*"- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958662/when-declaring-two-functions-with-the-same-name-in-a-global-scope-the-second-on or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603985/invoke-two-functions-with-the-same-name. The second declarations overwrites the first one.

Answer (score -2):

The `NaN` result occurs because the default values for the `rows` and `columns` parameters are being multiplied together, and it's possible that the `rows` or `columns` variables may have been assigned a non-numeric value elsewhere in your code. To debug the issue, you can add logging to check the types and values of the input arguments.

```
function monitorCount(rows = 5, columns = 3) {
  console.log(typeof rows, typeof columns); // Check the types of the input arguments
  console.log(rows, columns); // Check the values of the input arguments
  return rows * columns;
}

console.log(monitorCount()); // Output: NaN
```

This will output the types and values of the `rows` and `columns` variables to the console, which can help you identify where the problem lies.

Comment: "*it's possible that the `rows` or `columns` variables may have been assigned a non-numeric value elsewhere in your code*" - no. Not when the OP is calling `monitorCount()` as they claim to do.

Comment: `it's possible that the rows or columns variables may have been assigned a non-numeric value elsewhere in your code` - this is not true.  The rows and columns parameters can only be set by calling monitorCount with arguments, even if you have other variables called rows/columns elsewhere in your code.